# Find the radius of convergence of the complex power series.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find the radius of convergence of the power series
>   $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\int_{|z|=1} \frac{\cos{\left(\frac{1}{z-10}\right)}}{z^{n+1}} \,dz\right) z^n$.

I have no idea how to approach this. I tried to solve the integral using the fact that $\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz=\int_a^b f(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t)dt$ and then applied the ratio test but didn't succeed.

Also, since $z \in \mathbb{C}$, we have that $\cos{\left(\frac{1}{z-10}\right)}$ is unbounded by the Liouville's Theorem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: ignore the specific function for the moment and consider the general expression $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\int_{|z|=1} \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}} \,dz\right) z^n.$$ Can you use the Cauchy integral formula to simplify the integral? Do you recognize the series that results?

Comment: Let me call the variable of the power series $w$, to not confuse it with the variable of integration $z$. On compacts inside the disc of convergence you can swap the integral and sum to get $\int_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{z}\frac{\cos(1/(z-10))}{1-w/z}dz=\int_{|z|=1}\frac{\cos(1/(z-10))}{z-w}dz$. Then you can apply Cauchy's formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sketch: Let $f(z)= \cos (1/(z-10)).$ Note that $f$ is holomorphic in $\{|z|<10\}$ but has a naughty singularity at $10.$ It follows that the power series of $f,$ centered at $0,$ has radius of convergence exactly equal to $10.$

On the other hand, the power series of $f,$ centered at $0,$ equals $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}z^n.$ There is a well known formula for $\dfrac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$ ...

Comment: Why does the power series of $f$, centered at $0$, have radius of convergence equal to $10$?

Comment: Because if $f$ is holomorphic in $D(0,r)$ then $f$ equals its Taylor series, centered at $0$ in the same disc. So the ROC is at least $r.$ But if $f$ has a singularity on the boundary, then  the radius of convergence is at most $r.$